# Unable to locate element in cucumber

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber

I am unable to locate element using cucumber as there are multiple elements by same id on page.

but out of them two is hidden but only one is visible.

I am using `@browser.element(:id, "findYourItin")`

Please help me out of this

Comment: What gem are you using to drive the browser? Is that Watir code? Can you share the html of the three elements?

Comment: '<div id="findYourItin"></div>' html is like this.
But this same entry is there three times but two such cases are hidden.
As a result it keep on searching and return timeout error after specified interval

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Watir, you could:

1. Get a collection of all elements with the specified id
2. Iterate through to find the visible one

This can be done using `find`:

```
your_element = browser.elements(:id, "findYourItin").find(&:present?)
```

You would then do whatever you want with the `your_element`. For example, get the text of the visible div:

```
puts your_element.text
#=> "The text of the visible div"
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider determining what part of the page/html makes the div visible or not. For example, the visible div might have a parent with a class. Searching for that parent and then the div would save the iteration. It is not always possible, but is worth considering.